# VNC with GUI running locally

Tags: user-interface, vnc

I don't like my MBP because it's flaming hot to the touch and about a million other reasons.  But I like its speed and its convenience for getting things done.

My question is, WHY can't there be a system for simply running the OSX (or other) GUI code locally on a portable device, (like an MBP or iPad) while having all the "heavy-duty" code being called across the network on another device (like a Mac Mini).

All GUI clicks seem to call either
1. instantaneous effects that are highly decoupled from complicated code (like making a button go in when it clicks)
2. heavy-duty code that can stand to have a few hundred milliseconds of latency.

Look, VNC is exactly what I want EXCEPT without the degraded compressed graphics and slight/unpredictable lagging of the GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [X Window System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) aka X11 has been doing what you want for 27 years, and if the network between your terminal and the server machine is decent, latency is minimal.  There is even an [X server for iPad/Phone/Pod](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ix11-x-server/id314915946?mt=8).

Edit: just stumbled upon [this new product](http://www.aquaconnect.net/mac-remote-desktop.php), looks like an RDP server for OSX, looks promising.

Comment: +0.5 for having the patience to answer a question that is more of a rant than an actual question. +0.5 for mentioning X11...